# dompdf no muestra el pdf lo descarga automatico

Tags: php

saludos estoy usando el dompdf pero en ves de mostrarme el documento en pdf lo descarga automático alguien podria darme una mano. lo estoy haciendo como dicen las intrucciones de esta manera

```
require_once("../dompdf/autoload.inc.php");

// reference the Dompdf namespace
use Dompdf\Dompdf;

// instantiate and use the dompdf class
$dompdf = new Dompdf();
$dompdf->loadHtml('hello world');

// (Optional) Setup the paper size and orientation
$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'landscape');

// Render the HTML as PDF
$dompdf->render();

// Output the generated PDF to Browser
$dompdf->stream();
```

segun el codigo debe de abrir la ventana con el pdf pero en ves de eso se descarga en pdf

Comment: El navegador debería tener la capacidad para mostrar archivos PDF directamente, ya sea como característica nativa o como extensión. ¿Qué navegador estás usando?

Answer (score 1):

Con DomPDF, para descargar el PDF se hace esto:

```
$pdf->render();
$pdf->stream("$name.pdf");
```

Pero cuando quieres visualizar el PDF en el navegador haces esto:

```
header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
$pdf->render();
$pdf->stream("$name.pdf", ['Attachment' => false]);
exit(0);
```

No obstante, para que esto funcione debes escribirlo **antes de haber pintado nada más**. Es decir, no puedes ejecutar esto cuando ya has abierto el <head> de la página.

Si ya lo has hecho y no puedes evitarlo, una alternativa es usar ob_clean() para limpiar el Output Buffer y así "eliminar" todo lo que se ha pintado hasta ahora:

```
ob_clean();
header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
$pdf->render();
$pdf->stream("$name.pdf", ['Attachment' => false]);
exit(0);
```