# como devolver el codigo de un pdf desde javascript?

Tags: javascript, ajax, pdf

Tengo el codigo de creación de un pdf en una variable de javascrpt y quisiera devolverlo al navegador para que lo construya y lo muestre. Actualmente lo que hago es guardarlo en una carpeta en el servidor y luego muestro con un ajax por eso se que el proceso de creación esta correcto, pero no se como hacer que solo lo muestre y el usuario decida descargarlo o no, sin tener que guardarlo en el servidor.

**aquí creo el pdf en php:**

```
$pdf = PDF::loadView('/PDF/ARC_PDF', ['dataNomis'=>$info]);
    $path = storage_path('app/public/tmp/pdf/');
    $fileName = 'PDF_'.$request->modo.'_'.$request->buscar.'.pdf' ;
    $pdf->save($path . '/' . $fileName);
    
    $data = [ 'name' => $fileName,
              'url' =>$path,
    ];
    return $data;
```

**Este seria el ajax que recibe la información y la muestra**

```
success: function (data) {
        $("#procesar").css("display", "none");
        //console.log("hola " + die(data));
        window.open("storage/tmp/pdf/" + data.name, "_blank");
        // ! eliminar registro
      },
```

**Este seria parte del codigo que esta en la variable del pdf:**

```
%PDF-1.7
1 0 obj
<< /Type /Catalog /Outlines 2 0 R /Pages 3 0 R >> endobj 2 0 obj
<< /Type /Outlines /Count 0 >> endobj 3 0 obj
<< /Type /Pages /Kids [6 0 R] /Count 1 /Resources << /ProcSet 4 0 R /Font << 
/F1 8 0 R /F2 9 0 R >> /XObject <<  /I1 10 0 R /I2 11 0 R/I3 12 0 R >> >>
/MediaBox [0.000 0.000 595.280 841.890]
>>endobj4 0 obj [/PDF /Text /ImageC ] endobj 5 0 obj
<</Producer (���d�o�m�p�d�f� �2�.�0�.�1� �+� �C�P�D�F)
/CreationDate (D:20230210225202+00'00') /ModDate (D:20230210225202+00'00')
/Title (���A�R�C� �S�U�N�A�D)>> endobj 6 0 obj
<< /Type /Page /MediaBox [0.000 0.000 595.280 841.890] /Parent 3 0 R/Contents 7 0 R
>> endobj 7 0 obj
<< /Filter /FlateDecode /Length 1956 >> stream   x��Y�n�H���+j9�Еz��
```

Comment: Usas alguna librería para la construcción del pdf?. Si es con `php` puro, necesitas usar encabezados y para usarlos no debes enviar la petición vía `ajax` sino de manera síncrona. Revisa este [enlace](https://parzibyte.me/blog/2019/12/23/mostrar-pdf-navegador-php/#:~:text=PHP%3A%20Mostrar%20PDF%20en%20navegador,-Varios%20navegadores%20actuales&text=Para%20servir%20un%20archivo%20PDF,en%20el%20navegador%20necesitamos%20encabezados.&text=Despu%C3%A9s%20debes%20mostrar%20el%20contenido,navegador%20se%20prefiere%20usar%20readfile%20.&text=El%20nombre%20documento.), creo que te puede servir.

Comment: estoy usando DomPDF para crearlo y el ajax recibe la respuesta

Comment: Tal vez la respuesta a [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/431035/dompdf-no-muestra-el-pdf-lo-descarga-automatico) pueda serte útil. Si no es lo que buscas, deja un comentario y exploramos otras opciones.